# In batch, how to list files of a specific directory?

Tags: batch-file

I need to go through all the directories except one (named "FORBIDDEN"), and to print for each of them all the files they contain.

So I wrote a batch script like this:

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d %cd%') do ^
if %%G NEQ C:\Users\ME\FORBIDDEN (dir /a-d %%G)
```

But the part `(dir /a-d %%G)` is not good because I get some errors saying that files were not find.

So, for each round of the loop, how to list all files present in the directory (whose path is in `%%G`) ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
for /d /r %%d in (*) do if not "%%~nxd"=="FORBIDDEN" 2>nul dir /a-d "%%d"
```

For each folder if it is not the excluded one, show its contents

**edited** to adapt to comments

To only include the files with full path

```dos
for /d /r %%d in (*) do if not "%%~nxd"=="FORBIDDEN" (
    for %%f in ("%%~fd") do echo "%%~ff"
)
```

Another option (that also includes files in the current folder) could be

```dos
dir /a-d /s /b | find /v "\FORBIDDEN\"
```

Get the full list and filter it, to only retrieve the lines that does not make reference to the excluded folder

Comment: it looks good but how would you display only the files (with their path) ? (and not the other dir comments), sorry I did not asked